# How to change an inherited method's docstring in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, docstring

Suppose I have a class structure like the following:

```
class BaseClass(object):
  def divide_reward_by_x(self, x, data):
    """
    Args:
      x: float
    Return:
      Reward value
    """
    return self.reward(data) // x

class SubClass1(BaseClass):
  def reward(self, data):
    """
    Args:
      data: one-dimensional numpy array
    Return:
      float of reward value
    """
    return np.sum(data)

class SubClass2(BaseClass):
  def reward(self, data):
    """
    Args:
      data: one-dimensional numpy array
    Return:
      one-dimensional numpy array of reward value
    """
    return data + 1
```

Notice that `reward` for SubClass1 returns a float but `reward` for SubClass2 returns a numpy array. This means that when `divide_reward_by_x` is called for SubClass1, it will return a float but when it's called for SubClass2 it will return a numpy array. I would like the SubClass documentation to reflect that. In other words, **the code itself is not specific to the subclass but the documentation ought to be!**

**What's the most pythonic way to do this with minimal documentation and code repetition?**

I recognize the following solution but am wondering if there's a more "minimalist" and "pythonic" way:

```
class BaseClass(object):
  def _divide_reward_by_x(self, x, data):
    return self.reward(data) // x

class SubClass1(BaseClass):
  def reward(self, data):
    """
    Args:
      data: one-dimensional numpy array
    Return:
      float of reward value
    """
    return np.sum(data)

  def divide_reward_by_x(self, x, data):
    """
    Args:
      x: float
    Return:
      Float of reward value
    """
    return self._divide_reward_by_x(x, data)

class SubClass2(BaseClass):
  def reward(self, data):
    """
    Args:
      data: one-dimensional numpy array
    Return:
      one-dimensional numpy array of reward value
    """
    return data + 1

  def divide_reward_by_x(self, x, data):
    """
    Args:
      x: float
    Return:
      numpy array of reward value
    """
    return self._divide_reward_by_x(x, data)
```

Comment: As an aside: If you are using Google style documentation, [it's *Returns* with an s](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#doc-function-returns).

Comment: Personally, I would use Python's new type hinting instead of documenting each argument and return value like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: It's hard to tell from this minimal example, but is there a good reason why the reward type varies from subclass to subclass? Also, `reward` should probably be defined as an abstract method in `BaseClass`, as its definition is required in a subclass.